# Fine tune doc2vec on gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim, nlu

I am new in NLU and I am doing a project on document embedding. I want to fine-tune the doc2vec model in gensim on my small dataset to see if it can help for document clustering. I read the tutorial on the website but they did not mention anything about fine-tuning. Where I can find doc2vec pertained on wikipedia or twitter on any big dataset.

Comment: Why do you think your need to fine-tune any already-trained model? (I'm not aware of many pre-trained `Doc2Vec` models for reuse, and I've not seen published work about fine-tuning. While you can keep training an existing gensim model, that introduces many thorny balance issues - it's not a well-understood straightforward practice, & it doesn't add new words for `Doc2Vec`.) More typical would be to train a fresh model on your text. How much data do you have?

Comment: (If you don't have enough, finding other texts from a similar domain to mix with yours may help as much or more than trying to use someone else's model.)

Comment: @gojomo, I totally agree that no existing source is available for fine tune word2vec or doc2vec. From what I understand, by fine-tune in this case, we add vocabs that does not exist already in the pertained corpus. It means that we have to change the hidden size layers, It is not like the traditional fine-tuning as in CNN model. Is it correct ?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with common fine-tuning practices on CNNs to make a comparison. But yes, in common negative-sampling or hierarchical-softmax `Doc2Vec` modes, adding new words – for both input and prediction – would require expanding the sizes of its internal training network weights, and is not currently supported by `gensim`.  How much data do you have? Why do you want to adjust an existing model, rather than train a new one, when you don't even yet have an existing model to build on?

Comment: @gojomo, I have around 1k of documents. But I can for example take doc2vec pretrained on wikipedia corpus and finetune it on my 1k corpus but as I said it does not make sense in this context.